# Spray, Slick, Spark - OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: scala, apache-spark, out-of-memory, slick, spray

I have successfully implemented a simple web service using `Spray` and `Slick` that passes an incoming request through a Spark ML Prediction Pipeline. Everything was working fine until I tried to add a data layer. I have chosen Slick it seems to be popular.

However, I can't quite get it to work right. I have been basing most of my code on the [Hello-Slick Activator Template](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/hello-slick-3.0). I use a DAO object like so:

```
object dataDAO {
  val datum = TableQuery[Datum]

  def dbInit = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
    try {
      Await.result(db.run(DBIO.seq(
        datum.schema.create
      )), Duration.Inf)
    } finally db.close
  }

  def insertData(data: Data) = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
    try {
      Await.result(db.run(DBIO.seq(
        datum += data,
        datum.result.map(println)
      )), Duration.Inf)
    } finally db.close
  }
}

case class Data(data1: String, data2: String)

class Datum(tag: Tag) extends Table[Data](tag, "DATUM") {
  def data1 = column[String]("DATA_ONE", O.PrimaryKey)
  def data2 = column[String]("DATA_TWO")
  def * = (data1, data2) <> (Data.tupled, Data.unapply)
}
```

I initialize my database in my `Boot` object

```
object Boot extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("raatl-demo")
  Classifier.initializeData
  PredictionDAO.dbInit
  // More service initialization code ...
}
```

I try to add a record to my database before completing the service request

```
val predictionRoute = {
  path("data") {
    get {
      parameter('q) { query =>
        // do Spark stuff to get prediction
        DataDAO.insertData(data)
        respondWithMediaType(`application/json`) {
          complete {
            DataJson(data1, data2)
          }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

When I send a request to my service my application crashes

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

I suspect I'm implementing the Slick API incorrectly. its hard to tell from the documentation, because it stuffs all the operations into a main method.

Finally, my conf is the same as the activator ui

```
h2mem1 = {
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:raatl"
  driver = org.h2.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before? I'm using Slick 3.1

Comment: The easiest way out is to run on Java8 as PermGen has been deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` is normally not a problem with your usage, here is what [oracle says about this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gbyuu).

> The detail message PermGen space indicates that the permanent generation is full. The permanent generation is the area of the heap where class and method objects are stored. If an application loads a very large number of classes, then the size of the permanent generation might need to be increased using the -XX:MaxPermSize option.

I do not think this is because of incorrect implementation of the Slick API. This probably happens because you are using multiple frameworks that loads many classes.

Your options are:

- Increase the size of perm gen size `-XX:MaxPermSize`
- Upgrade to Java 8. [The perm gen space is now replaced with *MetaSpace* which is tuned automatically](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122)

Comment: Changed to Java 8 and voila!